# 16.04 Black Screen with Mouse Pointer after wake from screensaver

Tags: 16.04

Affects multiple systems

Current system:
32G Ram
Intel® Core™ i9-9900K CPU @ 3.60GHz × 16 
AMD Radeon (TM) R9 380 Series (TONGA / DRM 3.23.0 / 4.15.0-72-generic, LLVM 6.0.0)
4.15.0-72-generic
16.04.1-Ubuntu

Issue:  Turning on screen in the morning displays a black screen with a moving mouse pointer.  Nothing else.

Solution: CtlAlt F1 brings up a terminal from which I can login; running 'startx' gives me a gui desktop with an "X" for my mouse pointer, and no other functionality.  CtlAltF2 brings me to a terminal from which I can reboot.

Steps to reproduce:  Turn off the monitor and go to bed.  Wake up, turn on monitor.

Turn off screen is disabled, suspend is disabled.

Same bug appeared on our previous system, which never had this issue until about 4-6 months ago when it started doing it every single day - 100% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Buddy first of all .. thats some config you are rockin'.

Ubuntu 16.04 uses lightdm for display manager. I have seen some bugs in the past regarding similar issues. I would recommend re-installing lightdm or upgrading your system to 18.04 lts.

`sudo apt-get purge lightdm`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install lightdm`

`dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

`reboot`

But as a personal suggestion, your system is really high end and I think you should be on at least the latest LTS version. Consider upgrading your OS.

As far as I can remember Ubuntu 18.04 LTS uses GDM for display manager.

Comment: I just built it - literally yesterday.  I went with 16.04 as my fifth choice... The amdgpu-pro driver won't install for varying reasons on 18.04 (or 19.10) nor will it install on OpenSuse (Leap and Tumbleweed.)  And on all of those, the opensource amdgpu driver gives terrible performance, low framerates, and unbearable screen tearing.  16.04 was the last time I could get good graphics on the R9380.  I will try re-installing lightdm; it is just strange the issue was the same on our previous system.

Comment: Give it a shot in a virtual machine.. may be they have made some updates recently. These things keep on changing very fast. I am sure AMD doesnt want to loose market share just because of a driver for linux. https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-635

Comment: lol...  I actually tried all four on the new machine.  I've had other issues with Ubuntu over the years, and thought "New system, new OS..." so went with OpenSuse, only to find what I eventually found in Ubuntu as well... the -pro driver won't install, and the open source driver is great for the RX- gpus, but not the R9.  It is one of those 'known issues' with linux, and it doesn't look like AMD cares to update their driver now that the slightly-newer-gen cards have kernel support... The R9 seems to be a lost series on Linux.

Comment: Thats too bad then. Things like these push people back to windows.

Comment: You have no idea...  I got the R9380 after a 14-month-long Nvidia driver bug with my GTX440 led me to switching to AMD.  When Ubuntu 18.04 wouldn't even boot to a GUI from the live image without booting to a recovery console terminal and removing the amd drivers (a bug which received zero responses from AMD and Ubuntu) I questioned the wisdom of switching to Linux, believing it to simply be too hard to figure out, or too hardware-specific to work on any but the most exacting systems (even though it used to work on ANY system!) which is what led me here.  And I am still questioning the wisdom.

Comment: Re-installing lightdm made no change.

Answer (score 1):

Since the latest release of the amdgpu-pro driver is for Ubuntu 16.04.03 your choice to use that version is correct.
I've had a similar problem, and could solve it with a tweak in grub (in case you haven't done it already):

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash **amdgpu.vm_fragment_size=9**"

However keeping an old distro could give you troubles after its support ceased.

Comment: Sorry... I guess I never saw that part of the installation instructions before.  I see exactly zero difference in performance, but now I'm curious just what change that *does* make.

Comment: ...and there was no change.  Problem persists.